# Manage one object inside list of object java

Tags: java, arrays, json, spring-boot

I have List of object that list of object is shown same object multiple time but only color field different for all duplicate object. I want to change response.

if anyone have solution for this create common method and pass this list and covert into as per my expectation response.

1.Actual Response

```
[
    {
      "id": 21,
      "startDate": "2020-07-21",
      "startTime": "10:28:34+05:30",
      "endDate": "2020-07-21",
      "endTime": "19:28:34+05:30",
      "eventName": "Stretegic Planing for Business Success",
      "location": "America Phoenix",
      "city": "San Jose de Gracia",
      "eventImg": "Image Url",
      "passport": false,
      "passportDiscountPercent": 5,
      "featured": true,
      "myFavourite": true,
      "color": "Yellow"
    },
    {
      "id": 21,
      "startDate": "2020-07-21",
      "startTime": "10:28:34+05:30",
      "endDate": "2020-07-21",
      "endTime": "19:28:34+05:30",
      "eventName": "Stretegic Planing for Business Success",
      "location": "America Phoenix",
      "city": "San Jose de Gracia",
      "eventImg": "Image Url",
      "passport": false,
      "passportDiscountPercent": 5,
      "featured": true,
      "myFavourite": true,
      "color": "Green"
    },
    {
      "id": 76,
      "startDate": "2020-07-21",
      "startTime": "10:28:34+05:30",
      "endDate": "2020-07-21",
      "endTime": "19:28:34+05:30",
      "eventName": "Stretegic Planing for Business Success",
      "location": "string",
      "city": "Villa Juarez",
      "eventImg": "Imgage url",
      "passport": false,
      "passportDiscountPercent": 5,
      "featured": false,
      "myFavourite": true,
      "color": "Red"
    },
    {
      "id": 76,
      "startDate": "2020-07-21",
      "startTime": "10:28:34+05:30",
      "endDate": "2020-07-21",
      "endTime": "19:28:34+05:30",
      "eventName": "Stretegic Planing for Business Success",
      "location": "string",
      "city": "Villa Juarez",
      "eventImg": "Imgage url",
      "passport": false,
      "passportDiscountPercent": 5,
      "featured": false,
      "myFavourite": true,
      "color": "Black"
    }
]
```

2.Expect Response

```
[
    {
      "id": 21,
      "startDate": "2020-07-21",
      "startTime": "10:28:34+05:30",
      "endDate": "2020-07-21",
      "endTime": "19:28:34+05:30",
      "eventName": "Stretegic Planing for Business Success",
      "location": "America Phoenix",
      "city": "San Jose de Gracia",
      "eventImg": "Image Url",
      "passport": false,
      "passportDiscountPercent": 5,
      "featured": true,
      "myFavourite": true,
      "eventType": [
            {
              "color": "Yellow"
            },
            {
              "color": "Green"
            }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 76,
      "startDate": "2020-07-21",
      "startTime": "10:28:34+05:30",
      "endDate": "2020-07-21",
      "endTime": "19:28:34+05:30",
      "eventName": "Stretegic Planing for Business Success",
      "location": "string",
      "city": "Villa Juarez",
      "eventImg": "Imgage url",
      "passport": false,
      "passportDiscountPercent": 5,
      "featured": false,
      "myFavourite": true,
      "eventType": [
            {
              "color": "Red"
            },
            {
              "color": "Black"
            }
      ]
    }   
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1:** Create Schema Classes

Initial Response Model:

```
public class InitialModel {
            String id;
            String color;
}
```

Final/Converted Response Model:

```
public class Model {
        String id;
        List<Color> eventType = new ArrayList<>();

        class Color {
            String color;

            public Color(String color) {
                this.color = color;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Step 2:** Iterate initial response and convert it to the final response

```
List<Model> modelList = new ArrayList<>();
List<InitialModel> initialModelList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<List<Model>>(){}.getType());

for (InitialModel initialModel : initialModelList) {

Model tempModel = null;

// Check if model with same id already exists
for(Model model : modelList){
    if(initialModel.id.equals(model.id)){
        tempModel = model;
        break;
    }
}

// Create new model if id doesn't exists
if(tempModel==null) {
    tempModel = new Model();
    tempModel.id = initialModel.id;
    modelList.add(tempModel);
}
tempModel.eventType.add(new Color(initialModel.color));


}
```

**Result Json:**

```
String resultJson = new Gson().toJson(modelList);
```

1.I have add your code but some error is getting

```
private List<EventCustomDTO> commonListView(List<EventDtoClass> eventDtoClassList) {
        List<EventCustomDTO> eventCustomDTOList = new ArrayList<>();
        List<EventDtoClass> eventDtoClasses = new Gson().fromJson(eventDtoClassList.toString(), new TypeToken<List<EventCustomDTO>>(){}.getType());
        for (EventDtoClass eventDtoClass : eventDtoClasses) {
            EventCustomDTO eventCustomDTO = null;
            for(EventCustomDTO model : eventCustomDTOList){
                if(eventDtoClass.getId().equals(model.getId())){
                    eventCustomDTO = model;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(eventCustomDTO == null) {
                eventCustomDTO = new EventCustomDTO();
                eventCustomDTO.getId() = eventDtoClass.getId();
                eventCustomDTOList.add(eventCustomDTO);
            }
            eventCustomDTO.getEventType().add(new TypesOfEvents(eventDtoClass.getEvenTypeId(),eventDtoClass.getColor()));
        }
        return eventCustomDTOList;
    }
```

Comment: Ain't this adding the model twice if it is already found? I think you should add modelList.add(tempModel); continue; to the null check?

Comment: what is put on jsonString ?

Comment: jsonString is the Actual Response JSON in java string format.

Comment: In this line error is getting : eventCustomDTO.getId() = eventDtoClass.getId();      Variable expected

Comment: I have required to pass List<EventDtoClass> not jsonString

Comment: @rajeshpatel Please Stack Overflow is not place where people should answer with implementations on your behalf. You got 2 answers both showing different implementation of your question concept. There is nothing more which can be done according to this question. If you want direct solution post on the sites where developers can be hired.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have different JSON in your expected result you will need to have 2 classes to serialize/deserialize from. Lets consider following classes:

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
private class ObjectA {
    public Long id;
    public String color;
}

@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
private class ObjectB {
    public Long id;
    public String eventType;
}
```

Now the code to obtain your expected result in this case would be something like this:

```
List<ObjectA> object = List.of(new ObjectA(1L, "green"), new ObjectA(1L, "red"), new ObjectA(2L, "yellow"));
object.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ObjectA::getId))
        .entrySet() // from map of grouped ObjectA's
        .stream()
        .map(entry -> new ObjectB(entry.getKey(), // GroupID
                                  entry.getValue() // list of grouped ObjectA's by current GroupID
                                         .stream()
                                         .map(ObjectA::getColor) // change to stream of all color strings from grouped ObjectA's by current GroupID
                                         .collect(Collectors.joining(", ")))
        ).forEach(System.out::println);
        //.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With output:

```
ObjectB(id=1, eventType=green, red)
ObjectB(id=2, eventType=yellow)
```

You can adjust that code simply for your use case.